# C++ template - type/value mismatch at argument

Tags: c++, templates

I am getting these errors,

> type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for
>   ‘template class SasEngineQueue’
>
> type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for
>   ‘template class SasEngineQueue’

but if I use template arguments of SasEngineQueue class with std::string, that is OK, but as the code below if I use std::vector, there are errors. why?

---

```
class SasEngine{
private:
    unsigned char addr;
    SasEngineQueue<std::vector, std::vector> sasQ;
    SasTCP_IP sasTransport;
};
```

---

```
template<typename exception_t, typename lp_t>
class SasEngineQueue{
public:
    ThreadSafeQueue<exception_t> exceptionQ;
    ThreadSafeQueue<lp_t> lpCmdQ;
    ThreadSafeQueue<lp_t> lpRspQ;
};
```

---

```
template<typename msgType>
class ThreadSafeQueue{
protected:
    queue<msgType> threadSafeQ;
    mutex mu;

public:
    int get(msgType& msg);
    void push(msgType msg);
    void pop();
};
```

---

```
template<typename msgType>
int ThreadSafeQueue<msgType>::get(msgType& msg){
    lock_guard<mutex> autoMutex(mu);

    if(threadSafeQ.empty()){
        //empty Queue
        return -1;
    }
    msg = threadSafeQ.front();
    return 0;
}

template<typename msgType>
void ThreadSafeQueue<msgType>::push(msgType msg){
    lock_guard<mutex> autoMutex(mu);
    threadSafeQ.push(msg);
}

template<typename msgType>
void ThreadSafeQueue<msgType>::pop(){
    lock_guard<mutex> autoMutex(mu);
    threadSafeQ.pop();
}

template int ThreadSafeQueue<std::vector>::get(std::vector& msg);
template void ThreadSafeQueue<std::vector>::push(std::vector msg);
template void ThreadSafeQueue<std::vector>::pop();
template int ThreadSafeQueue<std::string>::get(std::string& msg);
template void ThreadSafeQueue<std::string>::push(std::string msg);
template void ThreadSafeQueue<std::string>::pop();
```

Comment: `std::vector` of what?

Comment: The template arguments of `SasEngineQueue` are not template-template arguments. What you're doing isn't allowed, and frankly make no sense. None of your template arguments are template-template arguments, yet you appear to be treating them all as if they were. I think you need to read up on how [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) works.

Comment: `SasEngineQueue<std::vector, std::vector> sasQ;` is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always point out where exactly the error is occurring - that makes it a lot easier for people trying to answer.

Anyway, the issue is that while `std::string` is a type (specifically, a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`), `std::vector` isn't. It's a template, and you need to specify the type the vector contains, e.g. `std::vector<int>`.

You might want to make it work for any vector - unfortunately, but that doesn't work, because explicit instantiations have to specify a concrete type.